# “type or namespace uPlibrary could not be found” in Unity when trying to unit test the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have the following Assets folder

`Assets
├── uPlibrary
├── Simulator
├── TextMesh Pro
└── Project
    ├── Scripts
    └── Tests
        ├── TestsAssb.asmbdef
        └── TestScript.cs
    └── MQTT
        ├── Script.cs
        └── Script.cs
    └── ScriptsAssb.asmdef`

the project works but when i add the test assembler definition using the test runner and the test scripts i get “type or namespace uPLibarary could not be found” i've searched for on the internet but not much on the topic.
i'm guessing this has to do with the asmdef files but i don't know how exactly.

Comment: You created an assembly definition and didn't not tell that definition about the existing assembly in the `uPlibrary` folder (which may be a dll)

Comment: actually that's what i wanted to do at first (i did the same with the TextMesh Pro package) but i couldn't find it